# How to get user input with vscode (no html)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

New to Javascript and I'm wondering how to get user input without using HTML but vscode only.

Any easy way of saving user input in a variable? something like:

`var name = input("What is your name?");`

`var name = prompt("What is your name?");`

I don't want to use an HTML form but just vscode console.

Thank you!

Comment: @slynagh what???

Comment: What do you mean vscode only? vscode console??

Comment: @epascarello I fully retract my previous statement - I have no idea what myself or the OP is talking about :/

Comment: @slynagh There's a delete link next to your comment.  Hover over it to see it, then flag anything referring to it as 'no longer needed'.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is basically running the script in the console.

Visual Studio Code has very little to do with this - though it does offer a terminal window([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)) for your convenience, I personally always use the linux terminal([docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_console)). But that's up to you.

So, to run javascript on the machine rather than the browser you need to install node.

- step 1: **install node**
  [here are the docs for that.](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/)

Now all you need to do is write your script and then run it.

- step 2: **write script**

`let name = prompt("what is your name");`

`prompt()` ([docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp))would get you the name prompt and store the input as the script is running in the terminal. so write your script let's say something like:

`nameProgram.js`;

```
console.log("Welcome to this awesome software that can tell you your own name!");
let name = prompt("What is your name?");
console.log(`Your name is ${name}! see how cool!`);
```

- step 3: **run program**

open the terminal whichever way you prefer, go to the directory of the script and type in the following command:
`node nameProgram.js`

That's it, your script will run.

Comment: @Alexxx glad i helped. remember to mark the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Trying to do this in VS Code, I get `ReferenceError: prompt is not defined`.