# Developing JavaScript on Windows with VS Code: how to handle prompt?

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code

I am developing JS on a Windows machine using VS Code as my code editor. I have a fairly simple script that I worked on for the Odin Project:

```js
let userInput = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the number you would like to FizzBuzz up to: "));

function makeNumberList(userInput) {
    let numberList = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= +userInput; i++) {
        numberList.push(i)
    }
    return numberList
}

function fizzbuzz(number) {
    if (!(number % 3)) {
        if (!(number % 5)) {
            return 'fizzbuzz'
        } else {
            return 'fizz'
        }
    } else if (!(number % 5)) {
        return 'buzz'
    } else {
        return number
    }
}

let numberList = makeNumberList(userInput)
console.log(numberList)
console.log(numberList.map(fizzbuzz))
```

I can execute that code in a browser by creating an `index.html` and inserting the code in a `<script></script>` html tag.

However, I can't get it to work in VS Code. I would like to be able to debug my code seamlessly on VS Code as it was executing in a brower.

I have stumbled across answers suggesting to use Node and different packages (`readline`, `prompt`, `prompt-sync`) - but that does not work on my side, I can't enter an input - as well as answers stating that Windows does not feature a proper prompt and I should therefore use the Windows Subsystem Linux  (WSL).

How can one use VS Code on a Windows machine to debug a JS script requiring user input in a prompt?

Comment: Best approach by far would be to *never use prompt* IMO, there are much more elegant methods to get user input - either an input field in HTML, or something like readline in Node. If your code has prompt in it, consider if you could change your application to remove it entirely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825384/alert-is-bad-really

Comment: Browser or cli?

Comment: `prompt` is a web API, if you want it to work in a Node environment you need some kind of polyfill.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225660/how-to-get-user-input-with-vscode-no-html